# Dynamically parametrizing class-level fixtures with pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixture

It is possible to parametrize test functions from command-line arguments.
It is possible to have a fixture scoped to a class.
I want to combine those two things, so that each class receives parametrized arguments that are given to the fixture within the class.

(essentially, per command-line argument I need to run one very expensive operation and then do a variety of cheap, speedy tests against the results of that operation, and I'd prefer not to have to rerun the expensive operation for each cheap test, so I'd like a way to save it)

In other words, I'm looking for an equivalent to pytest_generate_tests(metafunc), that would work for dynamically parametrizing a fixture, not a test function.

One thing I have already tried unusccessfully is reading the request parameters and setting *those* via the pytest_generate_tests hook.

```
conftest.py:
    def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
        metafunc.parametrize("result", [
                (1,0),(1,2)
            ])

test_thing.py:
    class TestThingy:
        @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
        def result(self, request):
            a,b=request.param
            return a+b

    #@pytest.mark.parametrize("result", [(0, 1), (1, 2)])
    def test_one(self, result):
        assert result!=2
```

Running this test causes the following error to be raised (note that the test ran fine when I tried it without the conftest hook and with the commented line uncommented):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def result(self, request):
    a,b=request.param
```

> AttributeError: 'SubRequest' object has no attribute 'param'

I'd also be interested in any other alternate way to achive the same result.

Comment: It would be great if the py.test team could weigh in. The docs are not clear on this point at all.

Answer (score 4):

I've done an ugly-hack-of-a-job at parametrizing a fixture based on command line args like this:

```
# contents of conftest.py
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--test-local", action="store_true", default=False)

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "dummy" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        #driverParams sets dummy[0], dummy[1] parametrically (as seen below)
        if metafunc.config.getoption("--test-local"):
            driverParams = [(True, None)]
        else:
            driverParams = [(False, "seriousface setting 1"), 
                            (False, "seriousface setting 2")]
        metafunc.parametrize("dummy", driverParams)

#driver can then be used as a standard fixture
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def driver(dummy):
    _driver = makeDriverStuff(dummy[0], dummy[1])
    yield _driver
    _driver.cleanup()

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def dummy():
    pass
```

Essentially what's going on here is that when `metafunc.parametrize("dummy", driverParams)` runs, it tosses `driverParams` into anything that relies on the dummy fixture. More importantly, it means that *the dummy fixture function never actually executes*.

Initially, I tried using metafunc to parametrize my driver fixture directly, and noticed that cleanup was never happening, because the (wrong) way I was doing things before was to `metafunc.parametrize` with `makeDriverStuff(param1, param2)` directly, and then scratch my head wondering why `driver()` was never getting called. The point of the dummy is to say, "Hey, there's a legit fixture here, don't complain that you can't find it!", and then always preempt it with something that's actually useful.

Like I said, it's an ugly hack. But you should be able to adapt it

Comment: I implemented this suggestion. I then added a print statement to check how many times the expensive code was being called. Unfortunately, the answer is over and over, for each test that gets the parameter.

Comment: In the case of what I'm doing, that's deliberate. My `makeDriverStuff()` spins up a new WebDriver (and thus a new browser instance), which I specifically want so that the tests are more isolated from each other.

Comment: Would changing the fixture decorators to have `scope="session"` (or class, or module, as appropriate) solve it for you?